# Какая нотация используется в стандарте ISO 14882?

Tags: c++, iso

Стало интересно, как читать стандарт. Формальные правила типа BNF, EBNF, Z, ASN.1 не коррелируют со стилем изложения в стандарте. Все нотации, что я посмотрел, используют либо `::=` либо `=` как знак определения, а в стандарте используется двоеточие.

```
assignment-expression:
               conditional-expression
               logical-or-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
               throw-expression
```

Конечно, можно положиться на здравый смысл, но стандарт штука очень формальная, а значит где-то должна быть и нотация для него.

Answer (score 4):

Там используется своя нотация, предназначенная для чтения человеком, а не для машинного парсинга как, например, BNF.

Краткое описание нотации дано в разделе [`Syntax notation [syntax]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/syntax):

> In the syntax notation used in this document, syntactic categories are indicated by *italic* type, and literal words and characters in `constant width` type.
>   Alternatives are listed on separate lines except in a few cases where a long set of alternatives is marked by the phrase “one of”.
>   If the text of an alternative is too long to fit on a line, the text is continued on subsequent lines indented from the first one.
>   An optional terminal or non-terminal symbol is indicated by the subscript “opt” [...].